# php boolean retrieval with binary operation

Tags: php

I have a piece source code to search with Boolean retrieval

```
<?php
$path = "Korpus";
foreach(glob("$path/*.txt") as $file) {
    foreach(file($file) as $line) {
    echo $line."<br>";
    }
}

$file = "";
$conv = ""; 
for($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++){
    $file[$i] = file_get_contents("$path/Doc".$i.".txt");
    $conv[$i] = explode(" ", strtolower($file[$i]));
    echo "<br>";
    print_r ($conv[$i]);
}echo "<br><br>";
?>
```

This is my Query

```
One AND Two AND NOT Three
```

I want the result like this

```
Term   Doc1 Doc2 Doc3
One     1    0    0
Two     0    1    1
Three   0    1    0

Result : Doc1, Doc3
```

can someone help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: By your example result your "query" should be `(One OR Two) AND NOT Three` or not?

Comment: @Cobra_Fast  The result is document name

Comment: @JohnConde thank you for warning, i will fix it in next question